# Any way to record the screen of an iPad commanding it with an Apple Pencil and see where it touches?

Tags: screen-recording, apple-pencil

I have to create a video that is a demonstration on how to draw something on the iPad using Apple Pencil 1.

I have tried recording using QuickTime on the Mac and also the screen recording capability of the device itself and the video does not show a circle to represent where the pencil is touching and neither show circles to representing fingers touching on the screen.

I mean a similarity like "show mouse clicks" when you record from the Mac screen.

Xcode's Simulator does this, but I cannot run the program I need in the simulator because it is a commercial app and the pencil does not work in the Mac.

Don't tell me that there is no solution!

Comment: I know this isn't about the question itself but on macOS, you can use specific softwares (or extensions (ex. for Chrome)) such as Screencastify (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?hl=en) which makes you aboe to choose options for your mouse pointer (circles around the mouse pointer when clicking for example). I am perfectly aware this does not answer your question, that's why I'm putting this in the comments. And also, I haven't tried but maybe you could try to install this extension on Chrome for iPad and try it on iPad? GL! :)

Comment: thanks I will check that out.

Comment: Tell me if it's working!

Comment: Not working. It does not record the screen of iOS devices.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the disturbance, I'll try to find an answer

Comment: no problem. Thanks anyway.